# How is the stack working for this assembly program?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am writing an assembly subroutine for calculating the length of string.

```
%include 'function.asm'

section .data
msg     db          'Hello this is yogi', 0AH

section .text
global _start
_start:

    mov     esi, msg
    push    esi
    call    strlength
```

Inside function.asm file,

```
strlength:
    pop    eax
    mov    edi, eax

loop:
    cmp byte[eax], 0
    jz finished
    inc eax
    jmp loop

finished:
    sub eax, edi

    mov edx, eax
    mov ecx, edi,
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h

exit:
   mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 80h
```

I've included only the concerned portion.
In short, what's happening is that I have passed string "msg" address in esi register. Then I pushed the contents of esi(which is the address of string) inside stack. Then I called strlength subroutine.

Inside the subroutine, I popped the address in eax, than  moved that address to another register "edi". So far, it's good and the program worked well.

The thing is that how is it working in the first place?

When I pushed "esi" into the stack, it was the first thing to be placed, then I called the subroutine and that means, it's address will be placed inside the stack too, then when I use pop command why does the string's address got popped, instead of subroutine's address. Because subroutine's address was pushed later, it was supposed to be at the top and therefore it should have been popped ?

I confirmed the same using GDB, the stack pointer was pointing to 0x********90, then when I pushed string's address it started pointing towards 0x********8c and later when I called the subroutine, it changed to 0x********88. Means everytime it decremented by 4 bytes. 
Inside the subroutine, when I used pop for the first time, it later incremented by 4 bytes and became 0x********8c.

can you guys help me with the concept? Am I mistaken about the working of stack or what.

Comment: `pop eax` will contain the return address IF you called the function (this is usually not the preferred way to start accessing arguments on the stack). If the code works it is by sheer luck or maybe because you are using the value in _ESI_., . You really should post all your code to make this an [mcve]

Comment: I've updated the code with full implementation. How should I access the argument on stack then ?

Comment: Something like `mov eax, [esp+4]`?

Comment: I got it, I had to dry run the stack functioning on my notebook. It's clear now. Thank you so much guys.